# Why does type-conversion/multiplication fail in Python for certain cases?

Tags: python, type-conversion, integer

I'm certainly a newbie to Python. Hence, I'm struggling to understand the results that the following bit of code gives me for i = 15 and i = 21. In all other cases is does what I expect.

```
import numpy as np

i_values = []
results = []
results2 = []

for i in range(27):
  i_values.append(i)
  result = np.int((i*0.02+0.03)*1.e2)
  results.append(result)

  result2 = (i*0.02+0.03)*1.e2
  results2.append(result2)

print i_values
print results
print results2
```

My question is: Why is the code working for most numbers but fails for certain values of i? I could solve the problem by

```
result = np.int(np.rint(((i*0.02+0.03)*1.e2))
```

but I just want to understand why it occurs in the first place.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "fail"? Which numbers, and what is the output for those numbers?

Comment: You can see that for 15 you get 32.9999 and for 21 you get 44.9999. `np.int()` keeps only the integer part, but `np.rint()` rounds to closest integer. As for why the answer is 32.9999, it has do with how floating numbers work and it has been answered before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this link should give you an insight:

[Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

It is understandable since the results can be slightly different due to precision if compared between how different languages deal with them. A quick example between using in python and just googling the answer:

[Python example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRErE.png)

[Google example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/houbE.png)